# How do I show that a continuous partial derivate makes the function differentiable?

Tags: general-topology, partial-derivative

Given a function $\mathcal f$: $\mathbb R^2$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$ that admits the partial derivates $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} $ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} $ in $\mathbb R^2$, how can I show that $\mathcal f$ is differentiable if at least ONE of these partial derivates is continuous?

Been banging my head for a while now and would appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Comment: Suppose that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous, and, for simplicity of notation, that $f(0,0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = 0$. Write $f(x,y) - f(0,0) = \bigl(f(x,y) - f(0,y)\bigr) + \bigl(f(0,y) - f(0,0)\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous. We have:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    &f(a_1+h_1, a_2+h_2)-f(a_1, a_2) = f(a_1+h_1, a_2+h_2)-f(a_1, a_2+h_2)+f(a_1, a_2+h_2) -f(a_1, a_2) \\
   &= \int_0^{h_1}  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1+t, a_2+h_2)\mathrm{d}t + h_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a_1, a_2)+o(h_2) \\
   & = \int_0^{h_1} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1+t, a_2+h_2) -
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1, a_2) \right) \mathrm{d}t + h_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1,a_2)  + h_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a_1, a_2)+o(h_2) 
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

The continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ implies its uniform continuity on $[a_1, a_1+h_1]\times[a_2,a_2+h_2]$. So, for small enough $(h_1, h_2)$, we have:

\begin{equation}
  \bigg\vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1+t, a_2+h_2) -
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1, a_2) \bigg\vert < \epsilon, \mbox{ for } t \in [0, h_1]
\end{equation}

Finally:

\begin{equation}
  f(a_1+h_1, a_2+h_2)-f(a_1, a_2) = h_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1,a_2)  + h_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a_1, a_2)+ o(h_1) +o(h_2) 
\end{equation}

And we conclude that $f$ is differentiable in $(a_1,a_2)$.